# Eclipse Workbench Select Workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, rcp, eclipse-emf

Even though all VM variables under *.product are correctly chosen as follows:

```
-Dosgi.sharedConfiguration.area=file:configuration
-Dosgi.sharedConfiguration.area.readOnly=true
-Dosgi.configuration.cascaded=true
-Dosgi.configuration.area=@user.home/.wg_wb/configuration
-Dorg.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
```

The SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=true can be seen under preferences, there is also no *.snap files to delete.

Only by using this version of plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar instead of org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar can I get the workspace prompt to work correctly.

Image below is from log Trace with the Exception thrown.
[image: Link to file log Trace with the Exception thrown.]

Comment: Is that the full stack trace? No 'caused by' part? Show us the trace as text, not an image. What version of Eclipse are you building?

Comment: That would be Eclipse DSL Tools Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0), I edited the question to include a Gdrive Link to the log file.

Comment: The launcher version for 4.10 is 1.5.200 why are you using much older launchers?

Comment: I thought that updates relevant to the launcher would be installed once I go in preferences=>Install/updates. I shall update to version 1.5.200 once I find out how that goes and post again.

Comment: When you build an RCP you should be using everything from the same release including the launcher.

Comment: Duly noted, it seems to install ECLIPSE DSL Tools instead of ECLIPSE OXYGEN seems to be the problem. How can I update my Workbench launcher or is the only answer to go back to the older version?

Comment: The launcher should always be from the core Eclipse you are using. Changing just the launcher to something else will not fix whatever problems you have. If you want to use the DSL tools from 2018-12 the rest of Eclipse should also be 2018-12.